# Highstock - translate indicators names

Tags: highcharts

In Highstocks the translation of Indicators names (indicatorAliases) doesn't work for me.

Translation of months' names and stock gui menu works fine
[image]

On the indicators popup translation of the add button works but despite setting indicator alias for "dema" I still see "DEMA" on the popup. I would expect to see: "Podwójna wykładnicza średnia krocząca" on the indicators popup:

[image]

and on the tooltip:
[image]

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/pbg7xhd6/
with the following translations:

```
Highcharts.setOptions({
  lang: {
    shortMonths: ["Sty", "Luty", "Marzec", "Kwi", "Maj", "Cze", "Lip", "Sie", "Wrz", "Paz", "Lis", "Gru"],
    stockTools: {
      gui: {
        elliott3: "Linia Elliotta 3 liniowa",
      }
    },
    navigation: {
      popup: {
        addButton: "Dodaj",
        indicatorAliases: {
          bb: ["Średnie kroczące Bollingera"],
          dema: ["Podwójna wykładnicza średnia krocząca"],
          williamsr: ["Wskaźnik Williamsa %R"]
        }
      }
    },
  },
});
```

Am I missing anything or doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The `lang.navigation.popup.indicatorAliases` property is not used to set the name of the indicator, but to set keywords for searching them using the search input.

Unfortunately, the name of the indicator cannot be changed using the API, which would be best reported on the library's Github repository: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/new/choose

However, you can overwrite the variable in the prototype of a given indicator and this solves the problem by changing the name in the popup and tooltip.

```js
Highcharts.seriesTypes.dema.prototype.nameBase = 'Podwójna wykładnicza średnia krocząca';
```

**Demo**: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/q2yme5hz/ 
**API**: https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/lang.navigation.popup.indicatorAliases